# Procedure run details for a day

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Please let me know if you can provide the detail of “number of times” a procedure has been called for that particular day, for the all the valid procedures.

Comment: I don't think you can see how many times a procedure has been invoked. When I want to know something like that I add a call to a logging framework (I use logger, available at oraopensource) as first line in each of the procedures/functions I want to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own logging technic. For example first you can create a table under the same schema of your desired procedure. Then after begin statement end before end statement in that invoked procedure, you can insert logs to newly created log table of yours.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.LOGTABLE
(
   DATECOLUMN    DATE DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
   PROCNAME      VARCHAR2 (200 CHAR),
   TABLENAME     VARCHAR2 (200 CHAR),
   MESSAGE       VARCHAR2 (1000 CHAR),
   LOGSEQUENCE   NUMBER
);


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PROCNAME IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SCHAME.LOGTABLE(DATECOLUMN,
                        PROCNAME,
                        TABLENAME,
                        MESSAGE,
                        LOGSEQUENCE)
    VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP,
            'SCHEMA.PROCNAME',
            'SCHEMA.TABLENAME',
            'Proc STARTED',
            NULL,
            SCHEMA.SEQ_SISTEM_LOG.NEXTVAL);

    COMMIT;


.....

INSERT INTO SCHAME.LOGTABLE(DATECOLUMN,
                        PROCNAME,
                        TABLENAME,
                        MESSAGE,
                        LOGSEQUENCE)
    VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP,
            'SCHEMA.PROCNAME',
            'SCHEMA.TABLENAME',
            'Proc ENDED',
            NULL,
            SCHEMA.SEQ_SISTEM_LOG.NEXTVAL);

   COMMIT;
END;
```